# Left join tables on nearest datetime without duplicating values

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am attempting to join `table_a` and `table_b` together on their nearest/closest `datetime` fields (`date_a` and `date_b`), but I am wanting to ensure that I do not receive duplicate values from `table_b` for each joined row. If the available `date_b` rows from `table_b` are used up on closer `table_a` values, then the joined row should just remain blank.

Another way of putting it: the datetime values from `table_b` can only be used once, and they should only be used on the absolute closest/nearest value from `table_a`.

Here's an example of `table_a`:

```
| entry_a |              date_a |
|---------|---------------------|
|       1 | 2019-02-20 01:05:00 |
|       2 | 2019-02-20 01:10:00 |
|       3 | 2019-02-21 01:15:00 |
|       4 | 2019-02-22 01:20:00 |
|       5 | 2019-02-23 01:25:00 |
|       6 | 2019-02-24 01:30:00 |
|       7 | 2019-02-25 01:35:00 |
|       8 | 2019-02-26 01:40:00 |
|       9 | 2019-02-27 01:45:00 |
|      10 | 2019-02-28 01:50:00 |
```

Here's `table_b`:

```
| entry_b |              date_b |       filename |
|---------|---------------------|----------------|
|       1 | 2019-02-20 01:03:00 | 20190220010300 |
|       2 | 2019-02-20 01:07:00 | 20190220010700 |
|       3 | 2019-02-23 01:23:00 | 20190223012300 |
|       4 | 2019-02-24 01:26:00 | 20190224012600 |
|       5 | 2019-02-25 01:30:00 | 20190225013000 |
|       6 | 2019-02-26 01:34:00 | 20190226013400 |
|       7 | 2019-02-27 01:40:00 | 20190227014000 |
|       8 | 2019-02-28 01:50:00 | 20190228015000 |
|       9 | 2019-02-28 01:51:00 | 20190228015100 |
```

And here's the desired result:

```
| entry_a |              date_a | entry_b |              date_b |       filename |
|---------|---------------------|---------|---------------------|----------------|
|       1 | 2019-02-20 01:05:00 |       1 | 2019-02-20 01:03:00 | 20190220010300 |
|       2 | 2019-02-20 01:10:00 |       2 | 2019-02-20 01:07:00 | 20190220010700 |
|       3 | 2019-02-21 01:15:00 |  (null) |              (null) |         (null) |
|       4 | 2019-02-22 01:20:00 |       3 | 2019-02-23 01:23:00 | 20190223012300 |
|       5 | 2019-02-23 01:25:00 |       4 | 2019-02-24 01:26:00 | 20190224012600 |
|       6 | 2019-02-24 01:30:00 |       5 | 2019-02-25 01:30:00 | 20190225013000 |
|       7 | 2019-02-25 01:35:00 |       6 | 2019-02-26 01:34:00 | 20190226013400 |
|       8 | 2019-02-26 01:40:00 |       7 | 2019-02-27 01:40:00 | 20190227014000 |
|       9 | 2019-02-27 01:45:00 |       8 | 2019-02-28 01:50:00 | 20190228015000 |
|      10 | 2019-02-28 01:50:00 |       9 | 2019-02-28 01:51:00 | 20190228015100 |
```

One thing to particularly note in the desired result: the last two rows show that `date_b.8` and `date_a.10` match exactly ... *but* if `date_b.8` and `date_a.9` are allowed to match, then `date_b.9` and `date_a.10` can match on something fairly close, also. (If this is an impossible complication, I understand. It's not critical. What's more important is the situation illustrated in rows 2-4 of the result_table.)

I am using MySQL 5.6. I've built a SQL fiddle here with the tables loaded up: **[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/734c3a/4)**

Thank you all very kindly for your help and for the many answers you've provided to guide me over the years.

Comment: What do you want to do when two records in `table_b` are equidistant from a record in `table_a`? Eg : for record `1` in `table_a`, both records `1` and `2` in `table_b` are exactly at a two minutes distance.

Comment: Either way would be fine. What would be additionally helpful is that the query would use one of the equidistant `table_b` records – _if needed_ – to meet up with another record in `table_a`, even if the other `table_a` record is farther away. So, for example, in `table_a` we have `10 | 20 | 30` and `table_b` has `10 | 15 | 25 | 36`. We would want to match `10` to `10`, `15` to `20` and `25` to `30`. Given the choice, it would be good to "save" the `25` to put it with `30`, and it'd be great for that to work in the "other" direction (`<`), too. Hopefully that makes sense. Thank you!